# Ignore indent of itemize for figures, lstlistings etc

Tags: floats, listings, indentation, itemize

I have a list of items where some of the items contain figures, listings, etc. How can I make these environments ignore the additional indent in an `itemize` environment?

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item
     Bla bla
     \begin{figure} 
        % indent should be ignored here!
        ... 
     \end{figure}
    \item
     More bla bla
     \begin{lstlisting} 
        // indent should be ignored here!
        ... 
     \end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: There's a magic word: MWE ...

Comment: The `figure` is floating away in that `\item`, so not really useful

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- Interrupt the `itemize` for the image and the listing.
- Use an `\hbox` for the image and the listing (this requires previously boxing the listing):

The code showing both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{lstlisting} 
// indent is ignored here!
code test text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

Some test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words
\begin{itemize}
    \item
     Bla bla
\end{itemize}     
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\begin{itemize}
    \item
     More bla bla
\end{itemize}     
\begin{lstlisting} 
// indent is ignored here!
code test text
\end{lstlisting}
Some test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words test text for the example and some more words
\begin{itemize}
    \item
     Bla bla\par\medskip

    \hbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
    \item
     More bla bla\par\medskip

     \hbox{\usebox\mybox}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it's best not to use the float `figure` for your image, otherwise the figure might float away from where you want it to appear (inside the `itemize` at a precise location). In case you need some caption for the figure, use `\captionof` from the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages.